# How CASE WHEN works in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Can anyone help me understand working of CASE WHEN statement in oracle.

Example data.

I have table **Employee** as below.

```
+--------+------------+-----------+
| emp_id | first_name | last_name |
+--------+------------+-----------+
|      1 | Foolish    | Much      |
|      2 | Silly      |           |
+--------+------------+-----------+
```

`last_name` is null for second record `Silly`.

Check the CASE WHEN now.

```
 SELECT CASE
            WHEN r.last_name IS NULL THEN 'Last name is null' 
            ELSE r.last_name
        END AS check1,  
        CASE r.last_name
            WHEN null THEN 'Last name is null'
            ELSE r.last_name
        END AS check2      
   FROM employee r
```

This gives below result..

```
+-------------------+--------+
|      check1       | check2 |
+-------------------+--------+
| Much              | Much   |
| Last name is null |        |
+-------------------+--------+
```

Why it is not giving Last name is null in check2?  I am expecting it to give Last name is null in both check1 and check2

Comment: For your particular example I would use NVL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, nothing equals `NULL`—not even `NULL`:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2     CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'true' WHEN 1<>1 THEN 'false' ELSE 'null' END,
  3     CASE WHEN 1=NULL THEN 'true' WHEN 1<>NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'null' END,
  4     CASE WHEN NULL=NULL THEN 'true' WHEN NULL<>NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'null' END
  5  FROM DUAL;

CASEW CASEW CASEW
----- ----- -----
true  null  null
```

That's why you have the `IS NULL` construct.

In case you're asking, this is a standard SQL concept, not an Oracle quirk.

**Edit:** In your example, [COALESCE()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) provides a cleaner solution and it's a standard function available in many DBMS:

```
SELECT COALESCE(r.last_name, 'Last name is null') AS check1
FROM employee r
```

Comment: Oops... I'll fix that ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this select, You have missed on word "is" before null then... in check2. also you have misplaced when keyword in check2 column.

```
 SELECT CASE
            WHEN r.last_name IS NULL THEN 'Last name is null'
            ELSE r.last_name
        END AS check1,  
        CASE
            WHEN r.last_name IS NULL THEN 'Last name is null' 
            ELSE r.last_name
        END AS check2      
   FROM employee r
```

Comment: please try now, EDITED

Comment: @collapsar: your statement is plain wrong. Of course you can use `WHEN ... IS NULL`. See here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e365/2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would you please mind to actually read the comments you disapprove of ? i was talking of the *simple* case expression which the op has been using, as should have been obvious from contrasting it to the *searched* case expression which is the one you use in your fiddle. in a *simple* case expression, you run into the very error that user Foolish mentioned: [sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e365/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e365/3)

Comment: @collapsar: But AK47's answer never contained a simple case expression. It used the correct searched case from the start. So I wonder on what you commented there. Plus: your comment implies that an expression is used after the `WHEN` because of the `...`. If you had written `CASE .. WHEN IS NULL` (which you obviously meant) that I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my apologies, you are right. my comment makes no sense (which i will therefore delete), plus i misread the second case expression in ak47's first version.